# Getting "bool(false)" from MailChimp API 3 POST request

Tags: php, curl, mailchimp

All,

I'm trying to do a simple "post" to Mailchimp using the 3.0 API; however I'm just getting a `bool(false)` response from the below code. I know the `MAILCHIMP_API_KEY` and `LIST_ID` variables are correct... Help?

All I want to do is add an email & first name to a specific list.

```
    $auth = base64_encode( 'user:'.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY);

    $data = array(
        'apikey'        => MAILCHIMP_API_KEY,
        'email'         => $email,
        'status'        => 'subscribed',
        'merge_fields'  => array(
            'FNAME' => $name
        )
    );

    $json_data = json_encode($data);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://'.$server.'api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'.NEW_LIST_ID.'/members/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Basic '.$auth));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);       
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    var_dump($result);
    die('<br /><br />Mailchimp executed');
```

Comment: try printing `curl_error($ch )` to see if there were errors

Comment: Run `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));` for more details.

Comment: FFS. I'd missed the dot after $server! Thank you both :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just missed the dot after `$server` in the URL, and also should be `email_address` rather than `email`. But below is a working example if anyone needs it:

```
    $auth = base64_encode( 'user:'.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY);

    $data = array(
        'apikey'        => MAILCHIMP_API_KEY,
        'email_address' => $email,
        'status'        => 'subscribed',
        'merge_fields'  => array(
            'FNAME' => $name
        )
    );

    $json_data = json_encode($data);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://'.$server.'.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'.NEW_LIST_ID.'/members');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Basic '.$auth));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);       
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    die('<br /><br />Mailchimp executed');
```